# Introjs highlighted area css issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, intro.js

I am using your introjs plugin but I have faced some issues.
The highlighted area becomes completely white. I am guessing that this is some CSS conflict because I am also using bootstrap.

What can I do to determine the cause of this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your code/jsFiddle?

Comment: I have fixed the issue. My custom bootstrap css was conflicted with your css. I just removed position:absolute in my css.